# Receiver Type Mismatch with Anko Layouts

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I am trying to create layouts with Anko DSL in my support v4 Fragment but the IDE shows receiver type mismatch. DSL works ok from the v7 AppCompatActivity. In trying to get this to work I have updated to Android Studio 3.0. I have also updated the dependencies in build.gradle's as some other threads suggested.

Here are the dependencies in my app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-commons:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4-commons:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$anko_version"
}
```

and the dependencies in project's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I have also seen this Question ['receiver type mismatch' with Fragment and Anko toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414041/receiver-type-mismatch-with-fragment-and-anko-toast)

But I am still stuck.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DSL works ok from the v7 AppCompatActivity

And in the list of candidates in the screenshot you can see it's defined as an extension function on `Activity`, and an `AppCompatActivity` is an `Activity`.

Your receiver (`this`) is the `HomeAdapter`, which doesn't extend `Activity`, `Context` or `ViewManager`.

If you call `context.verticalLayout` it will compile, but I don't know whether the result is what you want.