# Anko toast in android studios - Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, anko

I'm having trouble getting a toast message to display. when I try to call it i get the following error

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun Fragment.toast(message: CharSequence): Toast defined in org.jetbrains.anko
public inline fun Fragment.toast(message: Int): Toast defined in org.jetbrains.anko
public inline fun Context.toast(message: CharSequence): Toast defined in org.jetbrains.anko
public inline fun Context.toast(message: Int): Toast defined in org.jetbrains.anko
public inline fun AnkoContext<*>.toast(message: CharSequence): Toast defined in org.jetbrains.anko
public inline fun AnkoContext<*>.toast(message: Int): Toast defined in org.jetbrains.anko
```

I too am new to kotlin, and a lot of my searching has turned up nothing, but I'm sure its something really simple.

The fix I found here
['receiver type mismatch' with Fragment and Anko toast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414041/receiver-type-mismatch-with-fragment-and-anko-toast)
hasn't helped me.

I've got these dependancies

```
dependencies {

...
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version" // For SnackBars
implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-commons:0.10.8'
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support.v4-commons:$anko_version"

}
```

and these imports

```
import org.jetbrains.anko.toast
import org.jetbrains.anko.support.v4.toast
```

What I'm struggling with kinda boils down to this

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    toast("this toast works")
   
    class Player() {
       fun score() {
          if (x) {
              //do this
          } else {
              toast("this toast doesn't work")
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

and it gives me the error seen above.

everything else seems to be working the way I want it to.

I guess I'm struggling to understand why something that I imported at the top of my MainActivite.kt won't work for everything with in my .kt

Answer (score 1):

Anko is deprecated. Please see this page for more information.

https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/blob/master/GOODBYE.md

and we feel it's time to say goodbye to Anko.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
val toast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, duration)
toast.show()
```

And instead of `applicationContext` type `this@MainActivity`. Another approach is to save your context as a global variable then just access it with `context.toast("Hello World");`

Comment: But I thought the point of the Anko libraries that I imported was to make it so that I could simply call toast("toasty") and get a toast message, instead of the longer code. And when I tried the longer code that you suggested before trying to use Anko, I would get errors in the context declaration in in the brackets, no matter what I tried.

Comment: Well, you can, but I think you need to add context in front as I wrote in my answer. Because when you call toast(message) from inner classes or functions it doesn't know to which context it refers. It will take the wrong context and crash your app because it can't attach it to that context.

Comment: So what would be my context then? Would I do MainActivity.toast("toasty")? Cause when I put this@MainActivity in the long form code, I still can't compile it.

Comment: I am not that great with Kotlin but I would try "activity.toast("toasty")" or "context.toast("toasty")"

Comment: So, nothing I put in front of it seems to be working for me. Both "context.toast" and "activity.toast" turn red, and if I put "MainActivity.toast" it says "no such function"

Comment: with activity I think it means to try "this@MainActivity.toast("toasty");"

Comment: That didn't work either... I don't understand why it seems like I the imported libraries aren't accessible by everything in the .it file...

Comment: Try to play with those context variables and maybe you'll get a solution to this problem. Anyway, there is always the option to use standard Toast.MakeText(). As much as I could find is that some people had this issue and some of them fixed it with context.toast() some of them didn't at all. So my advice is to try creating a variable context with your activity context and then calling toast with that context.